# Are there two computable numbers in the unit interval that map to the same point under a space-filling curve?

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves, dimension-theory-analysis

A space-filling plane curve is a continuous surjective function from the unit interval $[0,1]$ to the unit square. Netto's theorem gives that continuous bijections preserve dimension, so a space-filling curve cannot be injective. In fact, for any given space-filling curve (e.g. the Peano or Hilbert curve), there are many points on the square whose preimage consists of multiple points in the unit interval.

For a given plane-filling curve (e.g. Peano or Hilbert), are there two specific computable real numbers in the unit interval that are known to map to the same point in the square? Do we have any characterization of the number of points in the square whose preimage contains multiple elements? Are those preimages always finite, or do some consist of infinitely many numbers in the unit interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hilbert curve definitely has the property that it maps certain pairs of computable numbers to the same point in the plane. Moreover, to see this we only need to consider rather few properties of it. I've explained this over at Mathoverflow:

[Is the Hilbert curve bijective over computable numbers?@MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349126/is-the-hilbert-space-filling-curve-bijective-over-computable-numbers/349133#349133)

It is not immediately obvious to me whether the argument extends to all computable surjections $\tau : [0,1] \to [0,1]^2$. Basically, any space-filling curve that "aims to be as injective as possible" will (ironically) fail to be injective on the computable reals. But maybe something which is highly non-injective on the non-computable reals could achieve being on the computable reals?

Comment: Do you have any intuition for what the set of points in the square to which the Hilbert curve maps multiple numbers in the unit interval "looks like"? It is countable? Dense in the square? Are the preimages of these points typically finite or infinite sets?

Comment: @tparker If you consider the curve to map intervals to squares on different scales, then whenever two squares have an edge in common, all but one points on that edge must have at least two preimages. Consequently, the set of points in the plane with at least two preimages is definitely dense and uncountable.

Comment: Do you know whether the preimage of any point has more than two elements?

Comment: @tparker If you think about what is happening at the corners where 4 squares meet, you should be able to conclude that some points (in fact, densely many points) in the plane must have at least 3 elements in their preimage for Hilbert curve-style constructions. But I don't see how that would lift to infinite, and a slight modification to the pattern would avoid that argument.